# ResponseCache always set Cache-Control to no-cache, no-store in ASP.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I want to cache the home page in the client browser

But after setting the ResponseCache attribute, the response header is set to Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store

After reading [Response cache not working in asp.net core project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53941473/response-cache-not-working-in-asp-net-core-project) and [ResponseCache not working in net core 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64413717/responsecache-not-working-in-net-core-3-1) I can't fix this

```
[ResponseCache(Duration = 300)]
public class HomeModel : PageModel
{

    public const string PageName = "Home";

    public void OnGet()
    {
    }
}
```

[image: CacheControl]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because I add a form in _layout.cshtml for search field an anti forgery token generated in it automatically!

ASP.net core set Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store for each page which contains an anti forgery field or has Authorize attribute!

By moving this form from the _layout.cshtml, problem resolved!

Comment: For me the problem was that I was using `Html.BeginForm()`, which generated the anti-forgery thing. I switched to an overload of `BeginForm` where I could specify `false` for the `antiforgery` parameter.

Answer (score -1):

Because I add a form in _layout.cshtml for search field an anti forgery token generated in it automatically!

ASP.net core set Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store for each page which contains an anti forgery field!

By moving this form from the _layout.cshtml, problem resolved!

Comment: It's like the Overflow stack site system has a problem in identifying the right answer!!! An answer that has been confirmed by at least 9 people can be given negative points by someone who is looking to collect site points and cause a flood of other negative points to flow to it.