# ASP.NET Core MVC is forcing no-cache if there is a form tag on the razor page

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, no-cache

I am a bit stuck with this. Troubleshooting some browser page cache issues and starting with a bare bones ASP.NET Core 7 MVC site. No matter what `ResponseCache` settings I have some middleware is forcing `caching` to `no-cache` if there is a `<form>` tag on the Razor page. Remove the tag and it works.

I cannot find any docs on this and this is not the behaviour I want or need.

Has anyone else seen this?

Comment: Could you please share how you are setting the cache header? have you test in different browser? are you using any custom middleware? refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69009216/responsecache-always-set-cache-control-to-no-cache-no-store-in-asp-net-core